# Link in entire table row seems not to use turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

Im referencing to [Link entire table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904938/link-entire-table-row)

I followed the instructions and now have a link in each table row:

```
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
      <tr onclick="location.href='<%= patient_path(patient) %>'">
        <td><%= patient.name %></td>
```

This generates for example such a link:

```
 <tr onclick="location.href='/patients/18'">
```

My problem is now that when i click on a link turbolink isnt used and it takes very long to reload the whole page! How do i have to change my code so that turbolinks is used? Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap the `<tr></tr>` or all `<td></td>`s in a `<%= link_to patient_path(patient) %>`? Turbolinks should pick up this link then.

Comment: Can you please explain my how i can wrap `<td>`s into `link_to`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of these versions, turbolinks should pick up any regular link.

```
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to patient.name, patient_path(patient) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
  <%= link_to patient_path(patient) do %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= patient.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
  <tr>
    <%= link_to patient_path(patient) do %>
      <td><%= patient.name %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```