# Is it semantically correct to put a table row <tr> inside an <a> tag?

Tags: html, semantics

This table contains data about a certain set of elements and I want every field of the row or else all the row altogether to allow the user to access the detail of each element. The thing is that I don't know how to proceed, I either:

Put the entire row inside an `<a>`:

```
<table>
    <a href=""><tr>…</tr></a>
    <a href=""><tr>…</tr></a>
    …
</table>
```

Or just put all the contents of every cell into an `<a>`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">…</a></td>
        <td><a href="">…</a></td>
    </tr>
    …
</table>
```

Of course I'd prefer the first one, but I don't know wether or not it'd be correct to do that.

This is one of the source from I got the idea of surrounding the row in an anchor tag:

[HTML5: Wrap Block-Level Elements with A’s](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links)

**Update:**

I think I have to be a little bit more clear on this, the table holds data to display an overview of the `Users` in the system:

```
+----+------+-------+
| Id | Name | Score |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  | Foo  | 10    |
| 2  | Bar  | 8     |
| 3  | Baz  | 5     |
| …  | …    | …     |
| n  | Zzz  | 0     |
+----+------+-------+
```

So I think it's correct to use a table, but each user has more than 3 fields of related information, so I would use a link to reach every user's detail (15+ fields) that'd otherwise be too much to display on a single row on a table (e.g. a 'comment' field of 2048+ characters); that's why I came up to the idea of displaying a link to each user's detal. Of course I don't care if the entire row is clickable, I just want to clear up the code a little bit by not having to surround all the data of every field into an `<a>`. Another solution would be to create an extra cell to specifically hold a link to the user's detail, like this:

```
+----+------+-------+-------------------------+
| Id | Name | Score |         Options         |
+----+------+-------+-------------------------+
| 1  | Foo  | 10    | (detail) (misc. option) |
| 2  | Bar  | 8     | (detail) (misc. option) |
| 3  | Baz  | 5     | (detail) (misc. option) |
| …  | …    | …     | …                       |
| n  | Zzz  | 0     | (detail) (misc. option) |
+----+------+-------+-------------------------+
```

But I don't know if that would be appropiate according to any user-experience guidelines too (in which case I think is less strict than any semantical rules, and a more sensible solution). Of couse I would include several `<a>` in the same field (table cell) for every different option, but I think that doesn't go against any semantical rule.

Comment: The first one is an invalid markup..so no, the second is your best bet.

Comment: If you want to be able to click on a table row, you'll need to use Javascript to add a click listener to it.

Comment: @tymeJV Well, I recently read that putting block-level () elements was now semantically correct according to HTML5 and it gave examples about `<div>`, `<h*>` and other elements, but nothing about `<tr>`s.  (Info here)[http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links].

Comment: @Barmar I'd prefer to stay away from js, as I'm following unobtrusive javascript dev.

Comment: `<tr>`s are not block-level elements, so no it won't work. In fact, the `<a>` elements will be ejected from the table by the HTML parser.

Comment: Asking whether something is “semantically correct” tends to be heavily opinion-based in HTML contexts, but here it is meaningless (semantically empty), since the construct is not even syntactically valid. It is not defined at all in HTML specifications, so it is pointless to ask what it “means”.

Comment: Well, I think asking for its meaning is the first step into finding information about the matter, including the fact that it doesn't have any meaning at all, so in a learning context I don't think it's entirely pointless. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you apply a link to the `<tr>` element, clicking **anywhere** on the row will send the user to the link.  This includes space that isn't a table cell, like the cell borders.

The same applies to the `<td>` element. Putting it inside links the text only, putting it on the outside links the whole element.

```
<a href=""> <td></td> </a>  //Links whole cell
<td> <a href=""></a> </td>  //Only links text inside <a>
```

Both your options work, but they *should* do different things. Generally, tagging a whole table row is semantically incorrect, as that leads to link overlap and other problems.

### Alternatively...

You can use *a bit* of JavaScript instead:

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="window.location.replace='...'"></tr>
</table>
```

**More about it:** [Link entire table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904938/link-entire-table-row)

Comment: I know what's the effect of each configuration, the question is which one is semantically correct, but I think I've already got an answer though.

Comment: Well, applying <a> to a whole table row is semantically incorrect, if that answers your question. It is recommended to use JavaScript instead.

Comment: However, the second option wouldn't integrate properly with some browser events (such as middle button click in new tab, ctrl+click, or other behaviours to come.

Answer (score 2):

Your first code is invalid markup, as a `<td>` can be the child of only a `<tr>`.  You *could* use your second code, but I would recommend using some JavaScript, like this:

```js
for (i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('td').length; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll('td')[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location.href = this.getAttribute('data-link');

  });
}
```

```html
<td data-link="http://example.com">text and content</td>
```

Comment: Perhaps something similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904938/link-entire-table-row

Answer (score 1):

Your second option is the semantically correct way to do it. You probably wouldn't have needed the table in the first place if all you were going to do was add anchor elements to it. You could have just added them into two separate spans.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "link" the entire "row", then it sounds likely that you don't actually have tabular data, and should consider something other than a `table` element.

Comment: The table holds data of a set of 'users' and every row would be a link to the user's details. So I think it's appropiate to use a table for the overview of the users, the idea of linking the whole row (not just the name for example) is that every field is related to the same user (i'd consider to include an extra field specifically to hold a link to the user's detail though).

Comment: That's tabular data then. A common idiom is to link only own column, or have an explicit "button" for going to details.  The 'javascript' route may make sense for you then.