# Mysql fetch - results with HTML links points to table ID

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink, fetch

I would like to display SQL results, each line with html link, where each link contains the table id.

My table name : fruits

```
table_id      content      description     price
 ---------------------------------------------------
   1          apple         tastes good    3 usd

   2          peach        grows on tree   4 usd

   3          plump         very purple    1 usd
```

It should display

```
Fruits

apple | tastes good
peach | grows on tree
plump | very purple
```

(Note: I haven't fetched price at this point)

My code so far:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT table_id,content,decription FROM fruits",$conn);

echo table

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
echo "<tr>";     

 echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";

 echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";

 echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

**What I want to achieve instead of echo :**

> a href="link to fetch id 1">apple | tastes good
>
> a href="link to fetch id 2">peach | grows on tree
>
> a href="link to fetch id 3">plump | very purple

When i mean "link to fetch id 1", i mean like href="www.application.com/another.php and some way to pass fetch id 1 or 2 or 3 to another php file.

How can i make these links ?

How can I catch the passed id in another php file ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use the POST or GET method to pass variables to the another.php file

Comment: Kepoly: so I should put my table into a form ... method=post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
while ( false!=($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) ) {
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td><a href="details.php?id=', urlencode($row['table_id']), '">',
                htmlspecialchars($row['content']),
            '</td>
            <td>', htmlspecialchars($row['decription']), '</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
```

you'd fetch the table_id in details.php from `$_GET['id']`. Test its existence first via [isset()](http://docs.php.net/isset)

For making the entire row "clickable" see [Link entire table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904938/link-entire-table-row)

Btw: the mysql_* extension is deprecated. Pick another API: mysqli or PDO_mysql.
see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php
And while you're at it and since you most likely are going to use _GET['id'] in another query, take a look at prepared statements and (named) parameters.

Comment: Thank you VolkerK, this is what i wanted ! Thank you!